# Delete all folders and files except for specified files?

Tags: windows-7, file-management, powershell

**Situation:**

I have multiple folders and files, which looks like this:

```
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\project1\english\folder1\file1
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\project1\english\folder1\file2
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\project1\english\folder1\file3
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\project1\english\folder2\file4
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\project1\english\folder2\file5
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\project1\chinese\folder1\file1
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\project1\chinese\folder1\file2
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\project1\chinese\folder1\file2
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\project1\chinese\folder2\file4
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\project1\chinese\folder2\file5
```

**Goal:**

I would like to delete all the folders and files except 'folder1' and 'file1', so that I'm left with this:

```
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\project1\english\folder1\file1
C:\Users\myname\Desktop\project1\chinese\folder1\file1
```

**Question:**

Can this be done with Powershell?

I asked a similar question before, and a brilliant user suggested the below solution, however it only deletes files, not folders.

```
$toKeep = "File1", "File3"
gci startFolder -Recurse | ? { !$_.PSIsContainer } | ? { $toKeep -notcontains $_.Name } | remove-item -WhatIf
```

Comment: What happens if you change to $toKeep = "folder1"

Comment: Tried that. It doesn't delete the other folders.

Comment: The `? { !$_.PSIsContainer }` part filters out folders, so the rest of the code only sees files. Start by removing that.

Answer (score 5):

Powershell 3:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\project1\english\" -File -Recurse |
Where-Object { $_.Name -ne "file1.txt" -and $_.Parent -notin ("folder1","folder2") } |
Remove-Item
```